# How to create index for Column that contain alphanumeric record in orientDb

Tags: orientdb

I have a string datatype column that contain alphanumeric data in orientDb.

When I create an index on it I get an error that property is not compatible with data type string .

How can I create an index for the following type of record:

```
34058
34034
340XX
34042
34030
857XX
34041
98087
90044
73160
9630
9112
9354
9855
9841
093XX
098XX
097XX
9049
9620
9366
```

Comment: Hi, can you please post the command executed? which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example and it works for me. This is my structure:

[image]

I've executed this command:

```
CREATE INDEX index_on_column ON Column (alpha) NOTUNIQUE
```

the index has been created correctly:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Regards